# Action and Jsp to get the iterator and display it

Tags: jsp, struts

This is my action class

```
public Iterator<CgConsultant> getSearchresult() {

        List<CgConsultant> list =userSearch.getConsultantMatches(searchstring);
        System.out.println("The size of the resutl list:"+list.size());
        Iterator<CgConsultant> iterator = list.iterator();
        CgConsultant obj;
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            obj = (CgConsultant)iterator.next();
            System.out.println(obj.getUsername());
            System.out.println(obj.getFirstName());
            System.out.println(obj.getLastName());
        }
        return iterator;
    }
```

And i have to populate the data in jsp and display it in the jsp

I m gettin the return status but how to populate the data n display it..

this is my jsp

```
<head>
    <title><fmt:message key="signup.title"/></title>
    <meta name="heading" content="<fmt:message key='signup.heading'/>"/>
</head>

<body>

        <h1> Search Complete</h1>
        <h2> Details are..</h2><br>

        <s:property value="Searchresult"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Please specify any suggestion..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taglib c is http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core

```
            <c:forEach items="${Searchresult}" var="cgConsultant">
                    <c:out value="${cgConsultant.username}"/>
                    <c:out value="${cgConsultant.firstName}"/>
                    <c:out value="${cgConsultant.lastNameName}"/>
            </c:forEach>
```

Add some nice html

Comment: yea.. m getting the index value of the array as the output.. 

java.util.AbstractList$Itr@1ddff76